# Plotting ellipsoids / oblate spheroids in rgl

Tags: r, rgl

I have been using `rgl` to plot spheres, but now I need to plot ellipsoids.
The package includes `ellipse3d`; however, this seems to be for fitting ellipsoids to data, using matrices and stuff I'm not very good at.

What I want is a simple way to plot ellipsoids, in a similar way to spheres, using the centre coordinates and the scales in each direction. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need the ellipse rotated around the axes, then you can just use a diagonal matrix for `x` (this plots a sphere, and defines the virtual "axes" along the x, y, z axes) and use the `centre` and `scale` parameters to shift the location and change the proportions.

```
plot3d(ellipse3d(diag(3),centre=c(1,2,4),scale=c(1,2,5)))
```

Comment: That's just the kind of simplicity I was after - Thanks so much! But is it also possible to change the scale on the axes, to shrink it a bit?

Answer (score 2):

There's one in my [cda package](https://github.com/baptiste/cda/blob/master/R/rgl.r),

```
library(cda)
library(rgl) 
## single ellipsoid
plot3d(rgl.ellipsoid(a=2,b=1,c=5))
```

[image]

```
## multiple ellipsoids, translated and rotated 
cl <- helix(0.5, 1, 36, delta=pi/6, n.smooth=1e3)
sizes <- equal_sizes(0.04,0.02,0.02,NROW(cl$positions))
rgl.ellipsoids(cl$positions, sizes, cl$angles, col="gold")
```

[image]